# Gnuplot doesnt draw lines

Tags: gnuplot

I need to plot CSV file which has simple table structure: first column - time in %H:%M:%S format, next columns header and some value for certain time.
Here example:

```
,A,B,C,D,E,F, ...
09:00:00,10,56,13,146,15
09:00:01,20,,,81
09:00:02,30,54,82
09:00:03,,,32
09:00:04,50,,105
09:00:05,,8
...
```

commands that i use

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M:%S"
set datafile separator ","
plot for[col=2:5] file.csv using 1:col with lines title columnheader
```

Everything is ok, just like i need. But if i want draw certain column like

```
plot file.csv using 1:"A" with lines title columnheader, \
file.csv using 1:"D" with lines title columnheader
```

Gnuplot prints

```
warning: no column with header "A"
warning: no column with header "D"
```

and empty plot but if i use points it works but still give same warnings

How can i draw plots with lines?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example works here if I quote the filename, with Gnuplot version 5.0 patchlevel 3. I do get this warning: `warning: no column with header "D"`, but the plot seems valid.

Comment: It is probably a bug.

Answer (score 0):

A few of your rows do not have a column D which is causing gnuplot to throw this warning when it attempts to read that column from one of those rows.  Pad the data rows so that they have all columns present (or at least the ones that you are using) and this warning will go away.  Also, quote the filename in the plot command.

```
,A,B,C,D,E,F, ...
09:00:00,10,56,13,146,15
09:00:01,20,,,81
09:00:02,30,54,82,           # only went up to C before
09:00:03,,,32,               # only went up to C before
09:00:04,50,,105,            # only went up to C before
09:00:05,,8,,                # only went up to B before
```

Remove the comments before using this file, but I have commented the rows with the problem for illustrative purposes.  Notice that I have added commas to those rows so that they have at least columns A - D.  You would encounter the same problem with plotting column F, for example, and will need to pad further in that case.